# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pk' in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i was trying to use bulk_create so that i can save to the database, but i have written the code which can save only one data but when i want to save multiple it gives me this error "**NoneType object has no attribute 'pk**'"

I have tried this, and my expectation was to save all shares at once according to number of members

```
def new_share(request):
    success_count = 0
    group = GroupMember.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
    attendance = Attendance.objects.filter(group=group,meeting__date=date.today())
    config = ConfigurationData.objects.filter(group=group).first()
    members = Member.objects.filter(group=group, is_active=True)

    for member in members:
        member.created_at = member.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 
    members_json = json.dumps(list(members.values()),default=str) 
    attendance_data = [
                    {'member_id': data.member.id, 'attended': data.attended}
                    for data in attendance
                ]
    if not attendance:
        messages.warning(request,f'Please make sure you have take an attendance for this meeting before you buy a share.')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        member_ids = [key.split('_')[-1] for key in request.POST.keys() if key.startswith('amount_of_share_')]
        print(member_ids)
        instances = []
        for member_id in member_ids:
            member = get_object_or_404(Member,group=group,id=int(member_id))
            amount_key = 'amount_of_share_'+ member_id
            amount = int(request.POST.get(amount_key,0))
            print(f'amount is {amount} and for member {member}')
            if amount > 0:
                try:
                    instances.append(ShareManagement.buyshare(request,value=amount,member=member.id))
                    success_count +=1
                except Exception as e:
                    messages.error(request,f"Error processing data for {member.memberID}: {str(e)}") 
                    print(f'Error processing data for {member.memberID}: {str(e)}')
            else:
                print(f'Process the fine for not buying a share for member {member.memberID}') 
        print(instances)        
        Share.objects.bulk_create(instances)  
        if success_count > 0:
            messages.success(request,f'{success_count} shares have been successfully saved.')  
            return redirect('app:share')       
                
    context = {
        
        'attendance':json.dumps(attendance_data),
        'config':config,
        'members_json':members_json,
        'members':members
    }
    return render(request,'shares/add_share.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi What does `ShareManagement.buyshare(request,value=amount,member=member.id)` do?
*instances* must be a list of model instances for bulk_create to work. It supposed to be something like this:

```
instances = [MyModel(field1='1', field2='2'),
             MyModel(field1='3', field2='4'),
             MyModel(field1='5', field2='6')]
MyModel.objects.bulk_create(instances )
```

but you append your list with results of this buyshare method

Comment: is the static function which implements the logic of calculating the share and create the object of the share then it returns the object

Comment: and what does ` print(instances)` output?